# New CPU Idles at 70C

Tags: cpu, cooling

I've just recently assembled a new computer, and the CPU (in the UEFI BIOS), reaches over 70C, and either stays there, or drops down to ~40C. I've checked the placement of my cooler (stock) and thermal paste, and they all seem in working order.

Specifications:

- Intel Core i7 2600K
- Corsair 650W (HX)
- ASUS P8P67 PRO
- Anything else you need?

Other than buying a new cooler/paste, what other solutions could there be, to getting this down to an acceptable temperature?

Comment: Well be glad it's only 70C and not 2600K instead...

Comment: The stock cooler comes with a REALLY thin layer of paste and it does NOTHING at all (at best). Buy a paste, remove the old one, apply the new one.

Comment: Or, if you plan to use the full potential of your i7 cpu from time to time, I would recommend you invest in a nice aftermarket cooler.

Comment: Any updates? Is your CPU still heating the room?

Answer (score 4):

** Read all of these suggestions / comments before trying to resolve your issue **

1. Intel usually has a pretty decent stock cooler and the one that came with yours should be no exception.
2. There is such thing as too much thermal paste, and rarely too little (unless you put none on at all) the amount I've see on the Intel stock is usually decent.
3. Try to jiggle the heatsink, there should not be much give - almost as if it's screwed to the side of the case - if it jiggles too much - try to re-connect.
4. I you have touched the top of our CPU or the thermal paste with your fingers, then use a dry, lint-free piece of toilet paper and remove the thermal paste, if it's still on, get some isoprophyl alcohol or mineral spirits and a lint-free cloth / tissue (no lotion in it) and remove the paste and re-apply using about a pea-sized amount of what thermal paste you have. The oils on your hand can interfere with cooling (think deep-fat fryer).
5. I would also see if there is an update for your UEFI BIOS in the event that it's reporting an incorrect temperature or there is a correction for thermal thresholds.
6. Boot into windows and make sure you have installed the latest updates as well as the supporting software for your motherboard including any hardware monitors and see if it is still sitting at 70C idling - it's possible that the thermal management is not on in the BIOS but may kick in while your using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a tough one.  If you just recently built everything I would say that you might want to check how the the CPU is seated.  Also, it could be a faulty sensor on the mobo, since it sometimes drops down to 40C.

Does your fan stop running intermittently?  Did you apply a thin even amount of paste to the CPU?  When the temp goes up to 70C is the processor under load?  I'm guessing that x86 apps that report the temp give you the same kind of readings right?  When you say you just assembled the machine, how long ago?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard bad things about stock coolers...

Is the heatsink getting hot as well?  If the heatsink is getting hot, you need more airflow.

If the heatsink is not getting hot, there is probably weak contact between the cpu and the heatsink.

Also, did you have to stick a sensor anywhere? Or is it reading the temperature sensor inside of the CPU?